# How to avoid stdin input that does not fit in buffer be sent to the shell in Linux 64-bit Intel (x86-64) assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, nasm, yasm

**Edit:** Title changed, as @Gunner pointed out that this is not a buffer overflow.

In reading user input from `stdin` with `NR_read` in Linux 64-bit Intel assembly, I wonder how can I avoid that the input that does not fit in the input buffer being sent to Linux shell eg. bash? For example in this example program I have defined an input buffer of 255 bytes (the size of the buffer can be whatever >= 1). The rest of an input longer than 255 bytes is sent to bash (if running from bash) and and this is obviously a serious vulnerability. How should input be read in Linux 64-bit assembly to avoid this vulnerability?

Here's my code:

```
[bits 64]

section .text
global _start

; can be compiled eg. with nasm or yasm.
; nasm:
; nasm -f elf64 read_stdin_64.asm; ld read_stdin_64.o -o read_stdin_64
; yasm:
; yasm -f elf64 -m amd64 read_stdin_64.asm -o read_stdin_64.o; ld read_stdin_64.o -o read_stdin_64

NR_read     equ 0
NR_exit     equ 60

STDIN       equ 1

; input:
; rax   number of syscall
; rdi   parameter 1
; rsi   parameter 2
; rdx   parameter 3
; r10   parameter 4
; r8    parameter 5
; r9    parameter 6
;
; output:
; rax   syscall's output
@do_syscall:
    push    rcx
    push    r11
    syscall      ; 64-bit syscall, overwrites rcx and r11
    pop     r11  ; syscall's return value in rax
    pop     rcx
    ret

@read_stdin:
    push    rdi
    push    rsi
    push    rdx
    mov     rdi,STDIN                ; file handle to read. STDIN = 1.
    lea     rsi,[input_buffer]
    mov     rdx,input_buffer_length  ; length of string
    mov     rax,NR_read              ; number of syscall (0)
    call    @do_syscall
    sub     rax,1                    ; get the number of writable characters.
    pop     rdx
    pop     rsi
    pop     rdi
    ret

_start:     ; linker entry point
    call    @read_stdin

@end_program:
    xor     rdi,rdi
    mov     rax,NR_exit  ; number of syscall (60)
    syscall

section .data

input_buffer         times 255 db 0
input_buffer_length  equ $-input_buffer
```

Comment: huh? you pass the `input_buffer_length` in, you make sure it don't excess your buffer size.

Comment: @J-16SDiZ `input_buffer_length` limits only the number of bytes to be read into my program. The rest of the input goes to Linux shell eg. bash and gets executed, and that is what I'm trying to avoid. In DOS most matters with keyboard could be handled with hooking the keyboard interrupt and using a custom keyboard interrupt, but it seems to me that that's not a correct way to do it in Linux (or is it even possible for non-root programs?).

Comment: Oh, you are asking how to clear the rest of steam before returning. Not how to limit the read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a buffer overflow as others have stated.  I wrote a tutorial on reading from the terminal in Linux which also shows how to deal with this issue.  It uses 32-bit Int 0x80, but you can easily change it to fit your needs.

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/286248-nasm-linux-terminal-inputoutput-wint-80h/

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solved my problem. I implemented input buffer flushing code in my own read input routine and it works nicely.

Comment: Well, at least it works, but dispatching a system call for each excess character -- doesn't sound reasonable. A larger tmp buffer would be an enhancement, but still... you never know which data come in if used, for example, in a pipe.

Answer (score 3):

The read syscall already has that protection built in. One other thing though: You shouldn't be explicitly using `syscall`. What if your code is taken to an x86-64 machine (which uses `sysenter`)? You should be using Linux's VDSO (virtual dynamic shared object), which contains code to do syscalls on all architectures, regardless as to wheather they support `syscall`, `sysenter`, or only `int`.

Comment: It's `lea rsi,[input_buffer]` (Load Effective Address, and it precisely stores the effective address in a register), equivalent to `mov rsi,input_buffer`. I prefer `lea` because it marks that the value stored in a register is a memory address. Further, `lea` can be used in more advanced addressing forms, you can compute `rax = rbx+8*rcx+7238` with only one `lea` instruction: `lea rax,[rbx+8*rcx+7238]`, and despite memory addressing syntax with `[ ]`, only memory address is computed in MMU, but no memory is addressed. In x86 `[ ]` do matter only with registers, not with memory addresses.

Comment: @nrz: Sorry! Completly forgot about `lea`. I'll get rid of that.

Comment: If I replace `syscall` (which works fine for me, at least NR_read, NR_write and NR_exit work - but with this problem in NR_read) with `sysenter` I'll get immediately `Segmentation fault`, already before I can enter any input inside my program. So, for some reason `sysenter` does not work at all. My custom kernel version is 3.5.3 and my processor is Intel Core i7-2760QM. And what do you mean with "What if your code is taken to an x86-64 machine (which uses `sysenter`)?" ? This is an x86-64 machine.

Comment: @nrz: Really? I thought only 64 bit AMD proccessors had syscall, I thought at only Intel processors had sysenter. That's bizzare. Or maybe, it's just x86 that only has sysenter.

Comment: Really. As Intel's `x86-64` processors are based on AMD's `amd64` architecture they must have `syscall` too, to be compatible. [Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual Combined Volumes: 1, 2A, 2B, 2C, 3A, 3B, and 3C](http://download.intel.com/products/processor/manual/325462.pdf) on Instruction Set Reference M-Z lists both `syscall` and `sysenter`. The text on `sysenter` says that "... the software must specify priviledge level 0 code segment and code entry point, and the priviledge level 0 stack segment and stack pointer ...". On `syscall` there are no such requirements.

Comment: So there are both `syscall` and `sysenter` available, but they are not directly exchangeable. I'm new to Linux 64-bit assembly and protected mode assembly in general (although I'm familiar with DOS x86 real-mode assembly), so I believe that the reason `sysenter` doesn't work in my code is that it requires setting up MSR addresses 0x174, 0x175 and 0x175 in appropriate fashion (according to Intel's 325462.pdf, link above), which I have not done in my code. On the other hand, `syscall` seems to require only correct parameters, so it's easier to use.

Comment: @nrz: the kernel should be setting up those msrs. I really thought Linux did. But you should still be using the vdso for your syscalls.

Answer (score 0):

You could read the input until newline character is found.