# String into an array/structure in assembly

Tags: arrays, string, assembly, x86, nasm

All I need to do is get the user-inputted strings and put them inside the array or structure, but I keep getting the error

> Invalid effective address

What does this mean?

#### The code

```
section .data
  fName db 'Enter your first name: '
  fNameLen equ $-fName
  lName db 'Enter your last name: '
  lNameLen equ $-lName

  numberOfStruct equ 50
  structSize equ 25
  firstName equ 0
  lastName equ 10


section .bss
  person resb numberOfStruct*structSize

section .text
  global _start

_start:
  mov esi, 0
  input_start:
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, fName
    mov edx, fNameLen
    int 80h

    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, 0
    lea ecx, [person+structSize*esi+firstName] ;This is where the error appears
    mov edx, 15
    int 80h

    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, lName
    mov edx, lNameLen
    int 80h

    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, 0
    lea ecx, [person+structSize*esi+lastName] ;This is where the error appears
    mov edx, 10
    int 80h

    inc esi

    cmp esi,10
    jl input_start

    exit:
    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 80h
```

Did I do it entirely wrong?

Comment: 25 is not a valid scale, only 1, 2, 4 and 8 are. You'll have to do the multiplication separately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:** Added code and edited answer to match changes in question.

```
lea ecx, [person+structSize*esi+firstName] ; this is where the error appears

lea ecx, [person+structSize*esi+lastName]   ; this is where the error appears
```

Both these have the same error: You cannot multiply with `25`, the valid scaling factors are `1`, `2`, `4` and `8`.

**Edit**: As Harold pointed out, `imul` is the easiest way to compute the address:

```
 imul ecx,esi,25                    ; ecx == 25*esi
 lea ecx,[ecx+person+firstName]     ; ecx == 25*esi + person + firstName
```

You can also compute the address by using 3 `lea`'s:

```
 lea ecx,[8*esi]                    ; ecx == 8*esi
 lea ecx,[ecx+2*ecx]                ; ecx == 24*esi
 lea ecx,[ecx+esi+person+firstName] ; ecx == 25*esi + person + firstName
```

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86#Addressing_modes) has a useful summary of all 64-bit, 32-bit and 16-bit addressing modes.

Comment: there, i should be person and lastName.

Comment: why can't i multiply with 25? but that's the size of one structure.  how can i input the string in the right place then? im lost.

Comment: @DoctorWhom the SIB byte can't encode it. Just do the multiplication manually.

Comment: @DoctorWhom Check edited answer. In x86 assembly programming there are a lot of arbitrary rules which you need to manage, such as the fact that in 32-bit and 64-bit addressing the only legal scaling factors are `1`, `2`, `4` and `8`, or the fact that for `mul` the other (implicit) operand is always `al`, `ax`, `eax` or `rax` and the result is always stored in `ax`, `dx:ax`, `edx:eax` or `rdx:rax` and the fact that for `shl`, `shr`, `rol`, `ror`, `rcl` and `rcr` the other operand must be either `cl` or an immediate value, other registers are not valid for that. It's designed that way.

Comment: So, why a double-width multiplication? `imul eax, esi` would work just as well, without killing `edx`, and you could do `imul eax, esi, 25`.

Comment: @harold You're right, signed multiply `imul` works fine here. Answer edited accordingly. `imul eax,esi,25` would overwrite `eax` which is already set in that point (but the instruction can be moved after `imul` without problems). `Using imul ecx,esi,25` does not require moving any other rows.

Comment: it works now! thanks guys!! but there's still a problem, when the input for the firstName has 10 characters the enter key goes to the lastName, so it skips the input for the lastName. can you understand my english? haha, sorry to trouble you guys but can i erase the enter key? if not, its still okay anyway. thanks again! :)

Comment: @DoctorWhom You need to flush the input buffer of `stdin` by reading for input in eg. in a 1-byte buffer until you'll get `0x0A` (line feed). I asked a question about that yesterday (for Linux 64-bit assembly) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459729/how-to-avoid-stdin-input-that-does-not-fit-in-buffer-be-sent-to-the-shell-in-lin and the solution (32-bit Linux assembly tutorial using `int 80h`) is here: [NASM - Linux Terminal Input/Output W/Int 80h](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/286248-nasm-linux-terminal-inputoutput-wint-80h/)