# sys_read will "spill" characters when buffer overflows

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm, system-calls

Using NASM for Linux x86

```
mov ecx,eax
mov edx,ebx
mov eax,3
mov ebx,0
int 80h
ret
```

EAX initially has a `mov`'d db constant, EBX has the length of the buffer

This is the code i am using to read from the console. It is working fine except for a single issue... i am asking for 2 chars, if i go over 2 chars and press enter, the next time i ask for input those "spilled"/extra chars will be fed into that request inmediately, with no user interaction. Should i fail to ask for input again, those extra chars will be interpreted by the shell as a command inmediately.

Example:

2 subsquent calls to this reading routine will yield:

```
2345
```

The second input request wont block nor prompt the user for anything at all, it just takes whatever chars it can. In both cases, i asked for EXACTLY two chars, on a 3-byte buffer filled with zeros.

1 call to the reading routine:

```
2345
$> 45: command not found
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? Should i use a different syscall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the input, you need to flush the buffer to avoid that the excess get passed to the next input read. It's not a buffer overflow, though.

I have asked the same question, but for x86-64 Linux, so it's not exactly duplicate:
[How to avoid stdin input that does not fit in buffer be sent to the shell in Linux 64-bit Intel (x86-64) assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459729/how-to-avoid-stdin-input-that-does-not-fit-in-buffer-be-sent-to-the-shell-in-lin)

Anyway, following GunnerInc's excellent tutorial (for x86 Linux) should solve your problem:
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/286248-nasm-linux-terminal-inputoutput-wint-80h/